# Ant Design version 4 form

Tags: reactjs, antd

How to read and validate **<Form.Item> value** in **children component**

In Ant 3.XX

we can pass **form** prop directly into the children component

`<ChildrenComponent formProp={form} />`

```
const ChildrenComponent = (props) => {

    const form = props.formProp.form

    <Form.Item>
        {form.getFieldDecorator(questionData._id, {
        rules: [{ validator: handleTextValidate }],
        })(<TextArea rows={4} onChange={handleChange} />)}
    </Form.Item>

}
```

but in Ant 4.XX, there is no **form.getFieldDecorator**

what should I do, to make **<Form.Item>** in children component controlled by **Form component** in parent component?

```
// parent

<Form>

    <ChildrenComponent />

</Form>

// children

<Form.Item>

    <Input />

</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved

**Parent:**

```
import {Form} from 'antd'

<ChildrenComponent formProp={Form} />
```

**Children:**

```
const Form = props.formProp

<Form.Item> <Form.Item/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `getFieldInstance` method to achieve that.

https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance

Comment: I read the document, I need to use <Form. Provider> to use this form instance. I don't know whether it's the best way or not. I will have a try, thank you